# Ao importar um dado CSV no jupyter notebook e transformar uma variável para 0 e 1 hora de mostrar novamente a tabela esta como NaN

Tags: python

import pandas as pd

train = pd.read_csv('base de dados')
train.head()

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#Mapear o sexo e trasnformar em 0 e 1
train['Sex_num']= train.Sex.map({'Female':0, 'Male':1})

#comparar utilizando a função loc para localizar os dados da linha 0 a 4 e a coluna Sex e Sex_Num

train.loc[0:4, ['Sex', 'Sex_num']]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se `Sex` pode ser `female` e `male`, tudo minúsculo, por que no `map` você colocou `Female` e `Male`?

Comment: Realmente foi isso, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Embora tenha visto que já foi solucionado.

Quando temos uma variável categórica, dependendo do caso, o uso de "category" é o ideal.

### Criando dataframe de teste

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Sex": ["male","male","female","male","female","female","male","male"]})
>>> df
      Sex
0    male
1    male
2  female
3    male
4  female
5  female
6    male
7    male
```

### Aplicando categoria

```
>>> df["Category"] = df["Sex"].astype("category")
>>> df["Category"].cat.categories = [0,1]
>>> df
      Sex Category
0    male        1
1    male        1
2  female        0
3    male        1
4  female        0
5  female        0
6    male        1
7    male        1
```

**Editado em 25/3/2021**

Baseado na pergunta do @Woss: "Como seria definido qual será 0 e qual será 1?"

Resposta: A definição é por ordem alfabética. Por isso o 0 é associado a *female* e 1 ao *male*

Veja outro exemplo:

### Nova base de teste

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Sex": ["outro", "male","male","female","male","outro","female","female","outro","male","male","outro"]})
>>> df
       Sex
0    outro
1     male
2     male
3   female
4     male
5    outro
6   female
7   female
8    outro
9     male
10    male
11   outro
```

### Aplicando categorias

```
>>> df["Category"] = df["Sex"].astype("category")
>>> df["Category"].cat.categories = [0,1,2]
>>> df
       Sex Category
0    outro        2
1     male        1
2     male        1
3   female        0
4     male        1
5    outro        2
6   female        0
7   female        0
8    outro        2
9     male        1
10    male        1
11   outro        2
```

Perceba que mesmo outro sendo o primeiro item, ele recebe a categoria 2. Caso queira associar em outra ordem, algo como `[0,2,1]` levaria a 0=female, 2=male, 1=outro

Comment: Qual é a regra que o pandas utilizaria nesse caso para determinar o mapeamento? Em  `Sex` temos `['male', 'female']` e seriam categorizados como `[0, 1]`. Como seria definido qual será 0 e qual será 1?

Comment: Muito boa sua pergunta. A ordem é alfabética. Atualizei o post.